# Transform mapped XPath expressions into XML containing relational data

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xpath, dictionary

### Background

Using XML and XSL to create a web site. The PostgreSQL database is structured to represent the requisite XML documents. PostgreSQL offers a number of XML-related functions, listed at:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html

This is a different problem than going from XML into the database, of which there are many solutions.

**Update:** To clarify, **this problem does not entail using XML functions** listed at the given URL. It involves a generic solution to create XML documents based on mapping database tables (and `JOIN` conditions) to XPath expressions.

**Update:** To further clarify, XQuery is for searching XML documents as though they were a database--like a cross between XPath and SQL. I have a database and I want to generate an XML document. The structure of the XML document should be given in terms of XPath expressions mapped to tables and columns, not in terms of XML functions.

### Problem

The problem I would like to solve is mapping values in table rows to XPath values using PostgreSQL. The example below serves to illustrate the problem.

#### Example

The XPath map, which is what this problem is all about, would resemble:

```
root               > people
person             > person
person.first_name -> name/first
person.last_name  -> name/last
person.age        -> [@age]
account.person_id => person.person_id
account            > person/account
account.number    -> [@id]
```

A `PERSON` table might resemble:

```
person_id | first_name | last_name | age
      123 | Peter      | Parker    | 18
      456 | James      | Jameson   | 42
```

And an `ACCOUNT` table might resemble:

```
account_id | person_id | number
         1 |       123 | 123456789
```

Querying the database using the XPath map would produce the following XML document:

```
<people>
  <person age="18">
    <name>
      <first>Peter</first>
      <last>Parker</last>
    </name>
    <account id="123456789" />
  </person>
  <person age="42">
    <name>
      <first>James</first>
      <last>Jameson</last>
    </name>
  </person>
</people>
```

In this case, James Jameson does not have an account and so the corresponding XML element (`account`) is not included in the final document.

This is a difficult problem and a complete solution is not necessary. A solution that  handles 80% of simple tables mapped to simple XML elements and attributes would suffice.

### Question

How would you create a SQL statement (or procedure) that returns an XML document based on a mapping of database tables (and a few JOIN operations) to XPaths (or similar) to perform the data transformation?

Are there any technologies, or open source implementations, that already perform such tasks?

Thank you!

### Related Links

#### Articles and White Papers

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-query2xml/
- http://www.thinkmind.org/download.php?articleid=dbkda_2011_6_20_30152
- http://www.informatica.si/PDF/33-3/06_Naser%20-%20Two-Way%20Mapping%20between%20Object-Oriented%20Databases%20and%20XML.pdf
- http://www.stylusstudio.com/sqlxml_tutorial.html

#### Commercial Software

- http://www.stylusstudio.com/db_to_xml_mapper.html
- http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should use a xml generating functions

```
postgres=# select xmlelement(name "people", xmlagg(xmlelement(name "person", xmlattributes(age), xmlforest(first_name as first, last_name as last)))) from person;
                                                                      xmlelement                                                                      
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 <people><person age="18"><first>Peter</first><last>Parker</last></person><person age="42"><first>James</first><last>Jameson</last></person></people>
```

(1 row)

there are other possibility use

```
postgres=# select table_to_xml('person', true, false, '');
                          table_to_xml                          
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 <person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">↵
                                                               ↵
 <row>                                                         ↵
   <first_name>Peter</first_name>                              ↵
   <last_name>Parker</last_name>                               ↵
   <age>18</age>                                               ↵
 </row>                                                        ↵
                                                               ↵
 <row>                                                         ↵
   <first_name>James</first_name>                              ↵
   <last_name>Jameson</last_name>                              ↵
   <age>42</age>                                               ↵
 </row>                                                        ↵
                                                               ↵
 </person>                                                     ↵

(1 row)
```

and next step should be some xslt transformation to your target format - here will be significantly better experts on xslt, and should help